# Pandas move headers

Tags: python, pandas, io, header, multiple-columns

I have extract a table from a website, however, the generated column headers have been misplaced.

For example,

Original table:

```
A A-explaned  B B-explaned C C-explaned
1  0.2 10%    2  0.7  20%  3 0.8  15%
1  0.2 10%    2  0.7  20%  3 0.8  15%
1  0.2 10%    2  0.7  20%  3 0.8  15%
1  0.2 10%    2  0.7  20%  3 0.8  15%
```

But what I get:

```
A A-explaned  B B-explaned C C-explaned  NaN  NaN  NaN
1    0.2     10%    2     0.7   20%      3    0.8  15%
1    0.2     10%    2     0.7   20%      3    0.8  15%
1    0.2     10%    2     0.7   20%      3    0.8  15%
1    0.2     10%    2     0.7   20%      3    0.8  15%
```

My desired table:

```
A A-explaned  A_    B   B-explaned  B_      C  C-explaned    C_  
1    0.2     10%    2     0.7      20%      3    0.8        15%
1    0.2     10%    2     0.7      20%      3    0.8        15%
1    0.2     10%    2     0.7      20%      3    0.8        15%
1    0.2     10%    2     0.7      20%      3    0.8        15%
```

How do I skip it every two columns and add another column title?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for `sep` parameter in read_csv:

```
from io  import StringIO
import pandas as pd
txt = StringIO("""A A-explaned  B B-explaned C C-explaned
1  0.2 10%    2  0.7  20%  3 0.8  15%
1  0.2 10%    2  0.7  20%  3 0.8  15%
1  0.2 10%    2  0.7  20%  3 0.8  15%
1  0.2 10%    2  0.7  20%  3 0.8  15%""")
df = pd.read_csv(txt, sep=r'-|\s+')

df
```

Output:

```
   A  A.1 explaned  B  B.1 explaned.1  C  C.1 explaned.2
0  1  0.2      10%  2  0.7        20%  3  0.8        15%
1  1  0.2      10%  2  0.7        20%  3  0.8        15%
2  1  0.2      10%  2  0.7        20%  3  0.8        15%
3  1  0.2      10%  2  0.7        20%  3  0.8        15%
```